# Python Regex: Picking one regular expression OR another

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that chooses to use one regex or another - depening on the input. Here is a simplified version on what my regex looks like:

```
string = '78 east easy street New York NY 11011'
REGEX = r'(?:' +\
            r'(?P<num1>6\d+)' +\
            r'|' +\
            '(?P<num2>7\d+)' +\
        r')'
m = re.match(REGEX, string)
```

My results look like this:

```
 78 east easy street New York NY 11011
    Matched: 78
    num1:   None
    num2:   78
```

My Questions are :
1. Why does both num1 and num2 appear in the results? Would it choose regex 1 or 2?
2. Is there a way to get a regex like the following to work (it would help when created complex pattern matching:

```
REGEX = '(?:' + '(?P<num>6\d+)' +  '|' + '(?P<num1>7\d+)' + ')'
```

EDIT: My expected output on the first snippet is to choose the right regex for the string, so either num1 or num2 on the output.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: My expected output on the first snippet is to choose the right regex for the string, so either num1 or num2 on the output.

Comment: How does your expected output differ from your actual output?

Comment: Also, your first snippet appears identical to your second output. Can you elaborate on what you intend the difference to be between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Why does both num1 and num2 appear in the results? Would it choose regex 1 or 2?

You have two capture groups, hence you will have both `num1` and `num2` appearing. It doesn't 'choose' one, it just goes through the first part that matches. You will get both capture groups whether all or none of the parts captured something because both are in the overall expression.

> 2) Is there a way to get a regex like the following to work (it would help when created complex pattern matching:
>
> ```
>     REGEX = '(?:' + '(?P<num>6\d+)' +  '|' + '(?P<num1>7\d+)' + ')'
> ```

The above works if you try it, just that you will now get `num` and `num1`. If you meant to have both groups named the same, then no, at least not in python.

You can have it in C# for instance, because the regex implementation allows capture groups with the same name.

In PCRE and languages implementing this regex engine (including the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module in python, but which is unfortunately not available in the current `re` module), you have "duplicate subpattern group" with the syntax:

```
(?| ... | ... )
```

Where if you have one capture group in each 'compartment', they will go into a single group, whichever of the two matches.

E.g.

```
(?|(?P<num>6\d+)|(?P<num>7\d+))
```

Will return the group named `num` with the part that matched.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Jerry's answer, you can do this using Python's [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module.

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = '78 east easy street New York NY 11011'
>>> m = regex.match(r'(?|(?P<num>6\d+)|(?P<num>7\d+))', s)
>>> m.group('num')
'78'
```

The conditional regular expression considered a *duplicate subpattern group* share the same number in any subpatterns in `( .. )` in such a group. If  the condition is satisfied, the first pattern is used; otherwise the second pattern is used.

As stated in the documentation:

> Groups with the same group name will have the same group number, and groups with a different group name will have a different group number. Group numbers will be reused across different branches of a branch reset... eg. `(?|(first)|(second))` has only group **`1`**.

Comment: Yes but would it be possible (for more complex regex) to do them seperate, as in my 2ns code snippet?